# .htaccess not working and gives me a "500 internal server error" warning

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I use codeigniter framework to create a shopping care, and I try to use the following code to redirect my page, but the web browser gives me a "500 internal server error" why is this ?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Can you check if you have Apache's `mod_rewrite` installed?

Comment: Where did you copy-paste this rewrite-rule from? In your first `RewriteCond` you are testing against a (partially) result of a previous `RewriteRule`-match (the `$1`-part) - which (obviously) isn't there

Comment: It from a ytb video of eduonix learning solutions

Comment: Besides my previous comment. You should check your apache-error log for a better explanation about what is going wrong. "500 internal server error" could really be anything

Comment: ^ indeed. it might not even be because of the code you pasted. figure out what the actual error is. enable error reporting if you haven't

Answer (score 0):

First check whether rewrite mode is already enabled or no using below command(Linux)

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and modify your `.htaccess` with below lines.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
#RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ $1.php [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
#RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ $1.html [NC]

</IfModule>
```